# How can a noun be countable and uncountable at the same time?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns, countability, countable-nouns

How can a noun be countable and uncountable at the same time?

For example '**shock**'.

> *You can get **a** shock.*

> *I'm suffering from __ shock.*

Comment: They're two different sentences, so not really "at the same time" - a noun is never *simultaneously* both countable and uncountable. Some nouns can be *either* countable or uncountable depending on context, just like some words can be either a noun or a verb depending on context.

Comment: I understand. But what has change, that 'shock' is countable in the first sentence and uncountable in the second?

Comment: The word *shock* means different things in the two sentences, and sometimes a word with multiple meanings  is countable in one meaning and uncountable in another.  Did you look up all the possible meanings of [shock](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shock)?

Comment: Thanks for that dictionary! Now I understand the difference.

Comment: @stangdon, even if we consider only the meaning of *electric* shock, it can be used as either count or non-count: "I got 3 shocks while repairing my TV", or "Electric shock is an occupational hazard for electricians".

Answer (score 1):

People talk a lot about countable and uncountable nouns, but this is really a misnomer.  Countability is not a property of a noun that might be similar to gender in other languages.  Rather, it is a property of the *sense.*

Consider *water.*  The sense that denotes the substance is uncountable: *I'd like some water please; I'd like a glass of water.*  But the sense that denotes a packaged quantity of water is countable: *I'd like an apple, a banana, and two waters, please.*

Consider your example, *shock.*  One sense denotes a discrete incident of surprise or electrical stimulation.  This is countable: *I touched the wire and got a shock; a tree fell in the yard, which was certainly a shock.*  Another sense denotes a state of mind: *After the cat jumped on my head, I was in shock for a few minutes.*

Answer (score -1):

English can be capricious. For example, "He drank *water*," uses *water as an uncountable noun.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meeting_of_Waters): "The Meeting of *Waters*... is the confluence between the dark (blackwater) Rio Negro and the pale sandy-colored (whitewater) Amazon River." Here, the two rivers are two waters, i.e., countable.

More peculiar yet: "He caught ten fish, salmon," shows *fish* as uncountable. "He caught two fishes, a salmon and a trout," uses fish as a countable noun.

Again, "pour wine," uncountable; "serving fine wines," i.e., of different types, countable.

[English Club](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-countable-un.htm) gives more examples.

There's no accounting for the innumerable idiosyncrasies of English.

Comment: While I agree that English can be capricious, you're overstating the case. In most of these cases a general rule applies: if _noun_ is uncountable, it may still be used as countable when it refers to one **kind** (or sometimes one **instance**) of the thing. This certainly accounts for your _wine_ example. Separately,  _fish_ is not uncountable in your example. _Fish_ can be uncountable when it refers to food ("We ate fish, cheese, and chicken" - all uncountable); but _ten fish_ is clearly plural. The plural of _fish_ is usually _fish_, though it can be _fishes_ in some contexts.

Comment: @ColinFine, there *is* a rule: if the fish are of the same type, the singular *form* is used, of different types, the plural *form*. However, for "water/waters," it's not clear. "He bathed in the waters of the Amazon," is interchangeable  with,  "He bathed in the water of the Amazon." While other languages were being reformed to make them more self consistent (there are *enforced* French language laws in Canada and France, for example), English is less consistent.

Comment: You're right that _water/waters_ is inconsistent. Note that _waters_ in **any context** (except maybe talking about different brands of bottled water) is poetic or archaic. I've no idea where you get your rule for _fish_ from, but it doesn't match the language I've spoken natively for over 60 years. When talking about the substance used as a foodstuff (even if it is in the form of discrete bodies) we use the uncountable _fish_ ("The fish is on the table"). When talking about more than one piscine animal, we use plural _fish_ ("The fish are swimming upriver"), (continued ....)

Comment: ... when there is a focus on the animals as individuals, some people use the plural _fishes_, but I don't think I ever use it except in a couple of fixed phrases. And you're right that some governments over the ages have attempted to legislate about language: apart from writing (which is an invented technology that must be laboriously learnt by every reader/writer, and so _utterly_ different from genuine human language) they have rarely had much success.

Comment: "ten fish" does not show "fish" to be uncountable; on the contrary, it applies a count of "ten" to it.  Rather, it shows that the plural of fish is irregular.  Lest you doubt that "fish" can serve as the plural form, consider "the two smaller fish in that photograph are minnows."